# uiimage oncomplete iphone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiactivityindicatorview

Is there such a thing as an "on load complete" for images in iphone?

I want to be able to destroy a UIActivity indicator once and image is loaded.

What the general best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to dismiss a `UIActivityIndicatorView` after a `UIImage` has been loaded and displayed properly in a `UIImageView`, you can try the following:

```
- (void)loadImageAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    // show the indicator
    [_myIndicatorView startAnimating];

    // give UIKit a chance to setup and draw the view hierarchy:
    [self performSelector:@selector(_loadImageAtPath:)
               withObject:path
               afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)_loadImageAtPath:(NSString*)path
{
    // load the image
    _myImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    // force the image to load and decompress now
    _myImageView.image.CGImage

    // image is ready, so we can remove the indicator view
    [_myIndicatorView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I have to admit, I did not test the above code. Please leave a comment if it works.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try implementing this shortly and will let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage` has a synchronous API. This means that when you create (or draw) a `UIImage`, it has been loaded and decompressed. This also means that a method call to creating (or drawing) a `UIImage` can block for as long as it takes to load that image.

If you want to do other things while loading an image, you have to load the image on a background thread, which is possible using the Core Graphics C API. `UIImage` is not thread safe and can be used on the main thread only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nikolai. Thats pretty interesting and to be honest went a little over my head due to my lack of experience o-0

Also all I really wanted to know was how can I know when an image has finished loaded so that I can remove a UIActivity indicator?

Maybe the answer was in your reply & I just don't get it? :)